# OCR for recognising handwriting in .NET

Tags: .net, ocr, icr

I need to use an OCR component within a .NET application that can recognise handwriting. We got the MODI component from MS office up and running, and it recognises printed text, but not handwriting.

I don't mind paying.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Many thanks
Jim

Comment: This may not be of much help but I found this: http://www.ocrtools.com/

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [Pegasus Imaging](http://www.pegasusimaging.com), we use it every day and it is great. For handwriting you have the ICR module.

Comment: Pegasus OCR component seems to be working fine and quite fast

Answer (score 2):

In my application, we had a need to recognize some forms that were filled in with hand-printed text. The accuracy was good as long as the users used well-formed characters. The SDK I used is called [Leadtools](http://www.leadtools.com/sdk/ocr/icr.htm). My application uses MFC but they also have .NET classes.

Answer (score 1):

Most OCR toolkits are aimed at recognizing printed text, not handwritten text. I would recommend [Atalasoft's toolkit](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/ocr/default.aspx) for flexibility in that you can plug-in various OCR engines.

Recognizing handwritten text is much less accurate and more difficult. It is usually labelled as [Intelligent Character Recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_character_recognition) (ICR), and I am not sure whether Atalasoft, Pegasus, or most commercial products support ICR. Hand-written recognition is aided by writing each letter in a cell on a grid, like filling out your name on the SAT. Are you talking about free form text or writing on a grid?

Comment: Flipdoubt: Writing on a grid in the style of an OCR form.

We have control over the form, so if there's a particular OCR form authoring toolkit that partners with a .NET component that would be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try [tessnet](http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/), it's an open-source .NET OCR engine based on tesseract

Comment: Tesseract clearly states that it does not support handwriting.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to distinguish between hand-printed text and cursive script writing. The term ICR generally is used to refer to hand-printed text.

Accusoft Pegasus provides a SmartZone ICR .NET  SDK that can get you recognizing text very quickly.  Accuracy get better and better as you gain control over how the text is entered, such as on a form, etc.

It also is important to realize that the cues available to real-time recognition, such as on a tablet PC, are completely different than those available in a scanned image. This is why cursive recognition is so much easier in real-time than after the fact (scanned image). You can read the movements of the pen, and the order of strokes is very helpful in recognition.