# Handwriting recognition

Tags: .net, wpf, handwriting-recognition

I know there's a handwriting recognition in wpf, but I'm not sure it supports images. What I want to do is give the program an image or screen shot of a handwriting or printing and it would recognize it and display on screen. Is it possible?

Comment: @Kheldar probably a horrible nit-pick, but in my mind OCR was always used for printed character recognition. Handwriting recognition is a good name for it. I don't know a lot about the subject, but in think most applications of handwriting recognition have been in live entry. But I've been out of the field for too....long. Mitch is right, way to open ended for Stack.

Comment: @Kenny: according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591574/ocr-for-recognising-handwriting-in-net, you're right, and it is actually ICR the OP is referring to. It's not obvious though, since imho ICR is much of a marketing name... I however have always seen OCR as englobing ICR, since handwriting is a form of using characters, not outdated by Gutenberg's invention :p

Comment: @Khedlard, bringing bible-thumping Gutenberg out on me eh!! ;)

Comment: This stuff lives in the Microsoft.Ink namespace.

Comment: Check out [tesseract OCR](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/)